# Colorability of planar graphs.

Tags: graph-theory, coloring, planar-graphs

**I'm trying to show that every planar simple graph with no cycles of length $\{4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11\}$ is $3$-colourable.**

Here is what I've done so far.

Let $S$ be the set of all graphs for which the statement is false.

Choose $G$ from $S$ with $\min V(G)=n$, say ie $G$ is the minimum counterexample.

I showed that $G$ can't have a vertex of degree at most $2$ and that $G$ doesn't have a cut vertex.

Next, I claim that if $H$ is in $S$, then $H$ has a cut vertex or a vertex of degree at most $2$.

I tried to show this by method of discharging by giving a charge of $d(v)-6$ to each vertex and a charge of $2|f|-6$ to each face. So the total charge given to the graph is $-12$.

I'm not sure how to proceed from here though.

Comment: Okay, what definition of *cycle* are you using? Because by the definitions I am familiar wtih, every planar graph without trivial vertices (ie, those with only 1 or 2 edges) has cycles of length between 4 and 11.

Comment: Cycle: Graph whose vertices can be arranged or inscribed in a circle st 2 vertices are adjacent if they're adjacent on circle.

Example: If I draw C12(cycle graph on 12 vertices), then it is a planar graph with no cycles of length between 4 and 11.

Comment: Only because it has trivial vertices. Do you include cycles that intersect themselves (i.e., a vertex appears on your circle more than once)?

Comment: Nope.

http://image.slidesharecdn.com/graphtheory-131025083802-phpapp01/95/graph-theory-10-638.jpg?cb=1382691919

These are cycles for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $H$ be in $S$.

Let $c(f)$: Charge of face $f$

$c(v)$: Charge of face $v$

Case 1: $H$ has a cut vertex. Then we're done.

Case 2: $H$ has no cut vertex

Give a charge of $d(v)-6$ to each vertex and a charge of $2|f|-6$ to each face.

Total charge $=-12$

If possible, $H$ has no vertex of degree at most $2$.

As $|f|\geq3$, therefore $c(f)\geq0$.

Thus, there exists a vertex $v$ st $c(v)<0$ ie $d(v)<6$.

Also, $d(v)\geq3$

Now, let every face of length $\geq12$ contribute a charge of $\frac{3}{2}$ to each of its vertices.

As $v$ is not a cut vertex, therefore it is adjacent to $d(v)$ different faces.

Also, if a face is a triangle, then adjacent faces can't be a triangle(otherwise we'd get a $4$-cycle).

Hence, all other faces have length at least $12$.

As $d(v)\geq 3$ ,it is adjacent to at least $2$ faces of length at least $12$,and hence it gets additional charge at least $3$.

Therefore, $c(v)\geq 0$

Now, $c(f)=2|f|-6-\frac{3}{2}|f|=\frac{|f|}{2}-6\geq0$ whenever $|f|\geq 12$.

Therefore, all vertices and faces now have positive charge(contradicts the fact that total charge is $-12$).

So $H$ has a vertex of degree $\geq 2$.

So claim holds, hence $G$ can't be in $S$(contradiction as G is the minimum counterexample).